# Automator to copy the image it's handling into the clipboard?

Tags: automator, graphics, copy-paste

I built an Automator sequence of actions to automatically scale by 50% my screen captures (use Apple's screenshot app).

I attached that sequence to the folder half-size where screenshot automatically saves the .png images.

I would like to also copy the scaled image to the clipboard. I tried the action "copy to clipboard" but that copies the path of the image to the clipboard, not the image itself.

[image]

Comment: Apple's clipboard is smart. If you copy an image file & paste to a text area, you see the name. If you paste it into an image viewer, you see the image.

Comment: I understand however that does not work for me: 
- If I select the image file in the Finder and press Command-C, then click a forum's text editor and press Command-V, I get the image (and it uploads the image file to the forum).
- If I run this Automator action and press Command-V into the same forum's text editor, I get the file path as text, and it does not upload the image file.

Comment: @Tetsujin - nobody likes an Apple fanboy. If I copy an image to the clipboard and paste it into a Messages window, I expect it to paste the image. Instead, the automator action copies the file path, and that gets pasted to the chat instead. Denying that the user's problem exists, and insisting that Apple knows best, is not productive.